# Enable plain HTTP (without SSL) access to WSO2IS entitlement service (PDP)

Tags: redirect, https, xacml, pdp, wso2-identity-server

I want to speed up access to wso2is PDP with changing from https to http.

All interactions occurs inside of seured network, so there is no security limitations.

I can't setup wso2is so, that PDP endpoint do not to redirect all requests from http to https port.

Is it possible? Can anybody help me with this quest?

Comment: So what you are essentially trying is to invoke the entitlement soap service via http?

Comment: I'm trying just to send XACML-request to pdp:
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -H "charset: UTF-8" -H "Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxx" -H "Accept: application/xml" -d "@mdp.xml" -X POST http://hostname:9763/api/identity/entitlement/decision/pdp